# Using pickle to log user's input without overwriting the file

Tags: python, pickle

I'm writing a program that takes user input and pickles it to a file. But everytime I run the python script it overwrites the file I designated. How can I start logging information with pickle where it stopped last? Or will I need to use another way?

Here's my current code for this.

```
1 import cPickle
2 from os import path, access, W_OK
3 from utility import Util #module contains finding file line length
4 
5 class Data_store:
6    def dump_data(self, var1, var2, fname):
7       PATH = '%s' % fname
8       
9       if path.isfile(PATH) and access(PATH, W_OK):
10          with file(fname, 'r+') as f:
11             cPickle.dump(var1, f, -1)
12             cPickle.dump(var2, f, -1)
13             f.close()
14       else:
15          output = open(fname, 'w')
16          cPickle.dump(var1, output, -1)
17          cPickle.dump(var2, output, -1)
18          output.close()

19    def load_data(self, fname):
20       obj = Util()
21       lnum = obj.file_len(fname)
22       with open(fname, 'r') as f:
23         #output = open(fname, 'r')
24          for i in range(0, lnum+1):
25             data = cPickle.load(f)
26             print data 
27       f.close()
```

Comment: If you only want to save your data to pickle before stopping, then save the data to a dict (or any pickle-able data structure) normally only save the dict to pickle when you about to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out Python's [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module.

> A “shelf” is a persistent, dictionary-like object. The difference with “dbm” databases is       that the values (not the keys!) in a shelf can be essentially arbitrary Python objects — anything that the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module can handle. This includes most class instances, recursive data types, and objects containing lots of shared sub-objects. The keys are ordinary strings.

Straight from the Docs:

```
import shelve

d = shelve.open(filename) # open -- file may get suffix added by low-level
                          # library

d[key] = data   # store data at key (overwrites old data if
                # using an existing key)
data = d[key]   # retrieve a COPY of data at key (raise KeyError if no
                # such key)
del d[key]      # delete data stored at key (raises KeyError
                # if no such key)
flag = d.has_key(key)   # true if the key exists
klist = d.keys() # a list of all existing keys (slow!)

# as d was opened WITHOUT writeback=True, beware:
d['xx'] = range(4)  # this works as expected, but...
d['xx'].append(5)   # *this doesn't!* -- d['xx'] is STILL range(4)!

# having opened d without writeback=True, you need to code carefully:
temp = d['xx']      # extracts the copy
temp.append(5)      # mutates the copy
d['xx'] = temp      # stores the copy right back, to persist it

# or, d=shelve.open(filename,writeback=True) would let you just code
# d['xx'].append(5) and have it work as expected, BUT it would also
# consume more memory and make the d.close() operation slower.

d.close()       # close it
```